# How to pass equations to Mathjax as strings?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, asciimath

I have javascript code that procedurally creates equations and stores them as strings. I want to use Mathjax to display these equations nicely, preferably using ASCIImath format. How can I pass these strings to Mathjax?

The reason I store the equations as strings is that otherwise javascript tries to evaluate them, which is something I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your content into the DOM and call MathJax to render it -- MathJax needs the DOM to properly render your content.

MathJax uses custom script tags to store math sources in the page. For asciimath the script type is `<script type="math/asciimath"> math content </script>`. See the documentation on [the MathJax processing model](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/model.html) for more details.

After you insert your content into the DOM, you need call MathJax. One way is `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` which will render all new content in the entire page (but not rerender everything).

You can also pass along DOM elements, e.g., via an id `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"mathId"]);`. See the documentation on [modifying math on a page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) for more details.